# Visual Studio Code not showing minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code

A new VS Code user (v.1.19.3) has minimap enabled in user settings:

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": true
```

but the minimap is not shown.  Toggle minimap also does not display it.

Can you suggest why this is happening please?

Comment: Any errors in the console? `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`

Comment: Workspace settings overwriting global ones?

Comment: Do you have a screen reader?

Comment: "Workspace settings overwriting global ones?" You're right!  Sorry, it had to be something simple.  If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex gave the correct answer: Workspace settings were overwriting global ones.

Answer (score 0):

type "settings.json" in the starter (search bar) on the top of the VSCode. In this file there might be autohide is set to true. If so then set it to false like following:

```
{
  "editor.minimap.autohide": false
}
```